# Is my proof for an invertible matrix correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a bit confused in class over some rules for proofs, so I was wondering if this was the correct proof for the following question:

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are similar $n\times n$ matrices and that $c$ is a scalar. Prove that $A−cI_n$
>   is invertible if and only if $B − cI_n$ is invertible.

My proof:

$A$ and $B$ are similar if $B=P^{-1}AP$ for some invertible $n\times n$ matrix $P$.

then $P(A-cI_n)P^{-1} = PAP^{-1} = B-cI_n$

Comment: There are typos in your last formula.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot something in the intermediate steps
$$
P(A-cI)P^{-1}=PAP^{-1}-PcIP^{-1}=PAP^{-1}-PP^{-1}cI=B-cI
$$
The first identity by *distributivity*, the second because $cI$ *commute* with all matrices, the third for the *inverse* property and the given similarity.